# AOT compiler - include lazy loaded external module

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-compiler-cli, angular-compiler

I am trying to include external module (hosted in git/npm repository) as lazy-loaded module in my Angular application.

I am compiling my external module with ngc compiler:

`node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json`

This is how my compiler config looks:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./release/src"
  },
  "files": [
    "./src/index.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "release",
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
    "entryModule": "index#ExternalModule",
    "skipMetadataEmit": false,
    "strictMetadataEmit": true
  }
}
```

And in my main app I am lazy loading given module:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
      { path: 'lazy', loadChildren: './lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule'},
      { path: 'external', loadChildren: '@angular-universal-serverless/external-module/release#ExternalModule'}
])
```

For compilation purposes I am using @ngtools/webpack plugin.

The JIT compilation works without any problems, but AOT compilation gives me error:

```
ERROR in ./src/ngfactory lazy
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/path/to/my/project/angular-universal-serverless/src/ngfactory/node_modules/@angular-universal-serverless/external-module/release/src/index.js' in '/Users/mtreder/Documents/private/work/angular-universal-serverless/src/ngfactory'
 @ ./src/ngfactory lazy
 @ ./~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
 @ ./src/main.server.aot.ts
```

So I decided to check what is the output from `ngc` compiler (whic is called under the hood by the webpack plugin):

`node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig.server.aot.json`

And in fact, my module is missing in the `/path/to/my/project/angular-universal-serverless/src/ngfactory/node_modules` catalog.

```
ls src/ngfactory/node_modules/
@angular        @nguniversal        @types          idb         ng-http-sw-proxy    rxjs            typescript-collections
```

**How can I force ngc to place given modules in the `ngfactory` output directory?**

My main application can be found here: https://github.com/maciejtreder/angular-universal-serverless/tree/externalModule

And external module here: https://github.com/maciejtreder/angular-external-module

Comment: How do you include your external module? npm i or npm link?

Comment: npm, as a dependency: "@angular-universal-serverless/external-module": "git+https://github.com/maciejtreder/angular-external-module.git",

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice it's externalModule branch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) The first problem here is that AOT compiler doesn't compile your module(`node_modules` folder is excluded by default), so you have to include it in `files` option of your ts configs:

**tsconfig.browser.json**

**tsconfig.server.json**

**tsconfig.server.aot.json**

```
"files": [
  "./node_modules/@angular-universal-serverless/external-module/release/src/externalComponent/external.module.d.ts"
],
"include": [
  "./src/main.browser.ts",
  "./src/app/lazy/lazy.module.ts",
  "./src/app/httpProxy/http-proxy.module.ts"
]
```

We can't add it to `includes` array because typescript will exclude it

> Files included using "include" can be filtered using the "exclude"
>   property

See more details in [the doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)

2) Then
**\node_modules\@angular-universal-serverless\external-module\release\package.json** should has `typings` field like:

```
"name": "@angular-universal-serverless/external-module",
"main": "./src/index.js",
"typings": "./src/externalComponent/external.module.d.ts", <=== this one
```

We have to use `external.module.d.ts` because angular doesn't create `ngfactory` file for `index.d.ts` while @ngtools/webpack plugin creates map for ContextElementDependency:

```
const factoryPath = lazyRoute.replace(/(\.d)?\.ts$/, '.ngfactory.ts');
// where lazyRoute === .../external-module/release/src/externalComponent/external.module.d.ts
const lr = path.relative(this.basePath, factoryPath);
this._lazyRoutes[k + '.ngfactory'] = path.join(this.genDir, lr);
```

If you don't want to change `package.json` then change `loadChildren` field:

```
{ 
  path: 'external', 
  loadChildren: '@angular-universal-serverless/external-module/release/src/externalComponent/external.module#ExternalModule'
}
```

[image]

Comment: After migration to Angular CLI, I am facing this issue again. The external module works perfectly for AOT compilation. But I am facing an issue with JIT compilation (`ng serve`).  Could you take a look or contact me somehow? All contact info can be found at https://www.maciejtreder.com

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's too late, but I hope this could help someone.

I wrote a very simple node script to be run right after `npm install`. It is indeed a post install script. It copies source files from `node_modules` into a folder under the main project. It then updates references to lazy loaded modules in the main routes file.

It worked perfectly for my team and we increased app performances very much.

The script is short and well documented, please check it out

https://gist.github.com/insanediv/8b4ebba06824a3eb8233e10287a1cdcd